# TinyMCE upload image: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, xml, laravel, file-upload, tinymce

please don't close this. I need help.

I have js function for uploading image with tinymce, and route on backend:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'#{{ $elementId }}',
    content_css: "{{ asset('css/tiny.css') }}",
    width: '100%',
    height: 600,
    plugins: [
        'lists preview hr anchor pagebreak link image wordcount fullscreen directionality paste textpattern table code'
    ],
    extended_valid_elements: 'svg[*],defs[*],pattern[*],desc[*],metadata[*],g[*],mask[*],path[*],line[*],marker[*],rect[*],circle[*],ellipse[*],polygon[*],polyline[*],linearGradient[*],radialGradient[*],stop[*],image[*],view[*],text[*],textPath[*],title[*],tspan[*],glyph[*],symbol[*],switch[*],use[*]',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | image | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | table | code',
    file_picker_types: 'image media',
    images_file_types: 'jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
    a11y_advanced_options: true,
    default_link_target: '_blank',
    automatic_uploads: true,
    convert_urls: false,
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
        let xhr, formData;

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;

        xhr.open('POST', '/upload-image');

        let token = document.getElementById("_token").value;
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            let json;
            if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                return;
            }
            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }

            success(json.location);
        };
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
        xhr.send(formData);
    },
    file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
        input.onchange = function() {
            let file = this.files[0];
            let id = 'blobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
            let blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
            let blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file);
            blobCache.add(blobInfo);
            cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
        };
        input.click();
    }
});
```

and in my controller for route /upload-image I have TinyMCE's postAcceptor script but I'm not sure how should I adjust it to my needs:

```
public function uploadImageWithTiny()
{
    /***************************************************
     * Only these origins are allowed to upload images *
     ***************************************************/
    $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://example.com");

    /*********************************************
     * Change this line to set the upload folder *
     *********************************************/
    $imageFolder = "public/img/";

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
        if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        } else {
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
            return;
        }
    }

    // Don't attempt to process the upload on an OPTIONS request
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS");
        return;
    }

    reset ($_FILES);
    $temp = current($_FILES);
    if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
        /*
          If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
          the configuration and enable the following two headers.
        */
        // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

        // Sanitize input
        if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
            return;
        }

        // Verify extension
        if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
            return;
        }

        // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
        $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

        // Determine the base URL
        $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? "https://" : "http://";
        $baseurl = $protocol . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "/") . "/";

        // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
        // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
        // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
        echo json_encode(array('location' => $baseurl . $filetowrite));

    } else {
        // Notify editor that the upload failed
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
    }

}
```

also I'm getting the error in console : `VM16752:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload`

in my console log for xhr.responseText I see that `xhr.responseText` is empty, so I'm assuming that is the error, but I'm not sure how to solve it. Also status for this request is 200, but something is missing. I'm stuck at this point and I would appreciate help!

How can I get location path from uploaded image?

Comment: Images are binary and can't be sent as HTML.  So be way of changing is to make them a Base64 string.  So use Convert.ToBase64String(byte[]) 
                Convert.FromBase64String(string)

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your answer. I'm not sure where should I do it or how, I've never use this before. Can you please tell me more about this?

Comment: Use File.ReadAllBytes(filename) and then convert to string when sending and then do opposite when receiving the file(s).